# How to change the tikz loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have defined the 21 points with `\path.a,b,c,d,...,u,`，

And I would like to draw like this:

```
\draw (a)--(b);
\newframe
\draw (a)--(b)--(c);
\newframe
\draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d);
\newframe
\draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--(e);
\newframe
\draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f);
...
\newframe
\draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f)....(u);
```

And I think is there any good method for this question use the tikz loop

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be nice if you gave a bit more info. I  initially thought `\newframe` was from `beamer`, though I see it is more likely from the `animate` package.  A complete example would have been nice.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% this is just to define the nodes
\foreach [count=\i] \j in {a,b,...,u}
  \node [fill,inner sep=1pt,circle,outer sep=0pt] (\j) at (\i/2,0) {};

% this draws the lines, using an overlay specification for \draw
\foreach [count=\i,remember=\j as \k (initially a)] \j in {b,c,...,u}
  \draw<\i-> (\k) -- (\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you are using `animate`, then this might work. It compiled without error at least, and judging by the log 20 frames were created.  I have no PDF-viewer that wanted to display the animation though.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\newcounter{upperbound}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ABC}
\begin{animateinline}[%
 controls,
 begin={\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\i] \j in {a,...,u}
    \node [fill,inner sep=1pt,circle,outer sep=0pt] (\j) at (\i/2,0) {};},
  end={\end{tikzpicture}}
]{5}
\multiframe{20}{iCount=2+1}{%
\setcounter{upperbound}{\iCount}
\foreach [remember=\j as \k (initially a)] \j in {b,...,\alph{upperbound}} {
  \draw (\k) -- (\j);
}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As for the animated version, the result works perfectly in AR.

Answer (score 2):

If you can rename the points something like `(p1)`…`(p21)`, then

```
  \foreach \j in {1,...,20}
  {
     \draw
     \foreach \i in {1,...,\j}
     {
        (p\i) --
     }
     -- (p\j);
  }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: And where do you include the new frame?? I suspect (because of the `\newframe`) that there should also be a `beamer` tag somewhere...

Comment: Renaming points is not necessary, see my answer.